# How do I pass form data to PHP and return a json string to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Does anyone know how pass form values into PHP and still return the data to JavaScript? (For use in Google Charts if anyone is wondering.)

I have an HTML form with 4 radio boxes. I'd like to pass the value of the form so that my PHP request will be modified based on the user's selection.

The results from the PHP request need to be passed to JavaScript for processing.

Comment: `radio boxes`? Do you mean radio **buttons** or **check** boxes?

Comment: Yes. Many ways. Do you want to stay on the same page (no page reload)? Or do you want to reload the page? Or go to a different page?

Comment: these would be radio check boxes. @bloodyKnuckles everything is being done on the same html page

Answer (score 0):

In the radio button on click event place a javascript function that will perform an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to  the php page and have the PHP page [echo](http://php.net/echo) some [JSON content that can be decoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in the return of the XHR in Javascript.

[Example of such](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp)

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you.
I think that you must do an [Ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( data) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + data);
});
```

You send data to server form your form (here sent are `name` and `location`). You read this data with javascript with [OnSelect](https://api.jquery.com/select/) and transfert it to your PHP code and,
You get back **`data`** from server into your JavaScript code and you can do what you want with it.
Sorry if my solution use JQuery, it is better for cross-browser with less code writing !

Answer (score 0):

You could use this line to parse an array into json and use it later in javascript:

```
json_encode($rows); //format array named $rows into json data
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php